# Is this a correct usage of "in which"?

Tags: word-usage

Would using "*in which*" be grammatically correct here?

> ABC presents an approach for object recognition using shape knowledge
>   **in which** a set of attributes describing the object shape and their spatial context are introduced in order to classify objects.

Comment: yes, it is correct

Comment: @Kevin: that mean no any grammatical errors of that sentence?

Comment: The error I see would be the conjugation of "are" with respect to "set".

Comment: @Kevin: thank you. that mean 'a set of attributes" should be singular?

Comment: yes, "a set" is singular.

Comment: @Kevin: still confusing because of attributes (plural case) ... so, if i ask my previous problem whether that is singular or plural  then; not 'a set of' but "a set of attributes"... does this still singular?

Comment: "of attributes" is a prepositional phrase describing "set".  It does not change it from singular to plural. So yes, "a set of attributes" is still singular.

Answer (score 2):

Whether *in which* is correct depends on what the sentence means, which is not very clear.

What does the relative clause modify? Is it
* *An approach to* [not *for*] *object recognition*, or
* *shape knowledge*?

If it modifies *approach*, then *in which a set of attributes ... are introduced* might be paraphrased:

> In [the course of developing/describing] this approach ... I introduce a [new] set of attributes.

That would be reasonably idiomatic. But if it modifies *shape knowledge*, *introduce* would imply something you are adding to existing 'shape knowledge', and you should use a different idiom:

> ... shape knowledge ***into which*** I introduce a [new] set of attributes.